# Order by lowest value of one column grouped by another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by, ranking

This was really difficult to explain in the title of this, but here is a table that I have:

```
CATEGORY_ID   COUNT   GROUPING
1             130     H
2              54     B
3             128     C
4              70     D
5              31     E
6              25     F
7              64     A
8              59     F
9              66     B
10             62     E
11            129     C
12             52     G
13             27     A
14            102     A
15            101     C
```

I'm trying to write a query to get the `TOP 5` `CATEGORY_ID`'s, first ordered by overall `COUNT`, but then based on that group use the other `CATEGORY_ID`'s in that group regardless of their `COUNT`. So, if I wanted to `TOP 5` of the above based on this rule (which I probably explained somewhat poorly), my result would be:

```
CATEGORY_ID   COUNT   GROUPING
6             25      F <-- THE LOWEST COUNT OVERALL
8             59      F <-- THE NEXT LOWEST IN GROUP 'F'
13            27      A <-- THE NEXT LOWEST OVERALL
7             64      A <-- THE NEXT LOWEST IN GROUP 'A'
14            102     A <-- THE NEXT LOWEST IN GROUP 'A'
```

I've looked a lot here and elsewhere (tried things like RANK(), DENSE_RANK(), GROUPING SETS, and more - mostly as stabs in the dark) and have hit walls all around.

EDIT: One additional thing is that I need to break ties of `COUNT` randomly. So, for example, if `COUNT` is `0` for all rows, then the first group returned should be random. I have tried this by adding `NEWID()` to the `ORDER BY` in both answers below, but with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a one step query.  Can you use a temp table?

Comment: If there were not exactly 5 total between the groups returned, would you still stop at 5?  For instance, suppose there were `3` entries in group `F`, and `4` entries in group `A`, you would display the `3` entries from group `F` and only the first `2` entries from group `A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
; with groups as (
  select
    grouping,
    min(count) as group_min
  from categories
  group by grouping
)
select top 5 c.category_id, c.count, c.grouping
from categories c
join groups g on c.grouping = g.grouping
order by g.group_min, c.count
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbcb3/4)

Edit:

To randomize in case of ties, you can add a random order to each group using `row_number()` and `newid()`:

```
; with groups as (
  select
    grouping,
    row_number() over (order by newid()) as random,
    min(count) as group_min
  from categories
  group by grouping
)
select top 5
  c.category_id, c.count, c.grouping
from categories c
join groups g on c.grouping = g.grouping
order by g.group_min, g.random, c.count
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01997/13)

Comment: This is great! There's one thing though: When count is 0 for all of the rows (which it will be initially), then I always get the same result set. What I need it for the first value to be randomly selected when all `COUNT`'s are tied. I tried adding `newid()` at the end of the `order by`, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @tptcat I'm assuming that you still want groups to be together... just the ordering of the groups as a whole to be randomized?  If so, please check out my second query...

Comment: Frederickson: Thank you so much. That's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Using `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`, so any tied records (such as when all counts are 0) would have the same ranking.  This allows ordering by `NEWID()` to give you random results.

```
;WITH CatByCount AS (
    SELECT 
        CATEGORY_ID, 
        COUNT,
        GROUPING,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT) AS ORD
    FROM theTaBle
)
SELECT TOP 5 CATEGORY_ID, COUNT, GROUPING 
FROM (
    SELECT I.CATEGORY_ID, O.ORD, I.COUNT, I.GROUPING
    FROM CatByCount O
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT A.CATEGORY_ID, A.COUNT, A.GROUPING
        FROM theTable A
        WHERE A.GROUPING = O.GROUPING
    ) I
) X
ORDER BY X.ORD, X.COUNT, NEWID()
```

Updated [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68a39/3)

Comment: All that fun work, only to come back and find a nicer version from @Michael Fredrickson :)

Comment: Thanks, @Bort. This is also great. However, it has the same issue as Michael's answer in that when `COUNT` is `0` I need the first `grouping` return to be random. I have posted an update in my original question. I can't seem to get this part to work.

Comment: My update includes using `RANK` and ordering by `NewID`, and the SqlFiddle has the results being ordered randomly when all the counts are 0.  What is incorrect with that?

Comment: @Bort Thanks. I still want the groups to be together when there's ties, but the ties should be broken randomly so that the first group isn't always the same.

Comment: OK I understand the difference, thanks for clarifying.  @MichaelFredrickson has it, so +1 to him :)  Interesting problem!